# CKEditor 3.6.3 - having issues with Styles

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

i'am having issues in ckeditor styles, when i select the some text and changing the styles. but it reflects into whole line. any solution for this.

Comment: CKEditor 2.6.3? There's no such a thing. CKEditor versioning started from 3.0. Previously there was FCKEditor. But it's so old that you should even think about using it.

Comment: @ Reinmar version 3.6.3. sorry for mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're perhaps applying block styles or changing format (format are in fact block styles). They are applied to entire paragraph/block, not just selected text.

This is close to how it works in MS Word (and exactly like in Libre Office), but with the difference that in MS Word it is possible to format part of block if you apply format on not collapsed (not empty) selection. CKEditor doesn't allow this because it creates HTML. And in HTML only entire block may be a header, paragraph, preformatted, etc. You can't change format of a part of block.

So if we're talking about behaviour of format combo and block styles - it is correct.

Comment: ok thanks. so that what you are saying is, in ckeditor if we select some values and change the styles the entire paragraph also change styles.

Comment: I modified my answer a little. I forgot about block styles. And yes - if you apply block styles it will affect entire block, not only the selected fragment.

Comment: @ Reinmar - so, we could not use all the MS Word patterns (texts) in CKEDitor.